# Design advice on a view

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, azure-cognitive-search

I have a view (`ObjectFlattenedView`) that flattens data points from various tables and views containing everything that has to do with the object of interest. Then, Azure Search indexes the output of this view for my ui to later issue search queries to locate the relevant records. Object has various attributes (columns in the view) that we might want to search by. The view is quite large as far as the number of objects and also the varying sources of attributes so performance is a major concern.

I have a new attribute that I need to add to this flattened view. Each object has 0 to many records in this `TableN` which has the following structure

```
ObjectId   SubNo   SubValue
A          Sub5    0
B          Sub1    0 
B          Sub2    1 
B          Sub..   .. 
B          SubK    0
```

Now I need to add this new attribute (`AttrN`) so that I can index the object docs (as Azure Search calls it) containing this new attribute. The flattened view would be something like this:

```
ObjectId Attr1...       AttrN    
A        abc.....       {Sub5:0}
B        abd.....       {Sub1:0,Sub2:1,...SubK:0}
```

My dilemma is the following:

If I flat out add a cte that concatenates the different sub-values of the object, the performance of the view worsens by 200% to 700%. The cte uses mssql's `stuff` and `for xml`. The execution plan does show ~8% of the overall cost to be this `for xml` statement. I know there will be a performance impact as I join more tables/views into my flattened view but the order of magnitude that I am getting hit with is quite high.

If I outer join my `ObjectFlattenedView` directly to `TableN`, then my view will have records for objects that are equal to 1 to the number of records that the object has in TableN. This complicates the Azure Search result handling such as how many records to get from Search and do the pagination as objects can have 0 to M records coming from `TableN`.

Has anyone come across with a similar issue and do you have patterns that you can suggest for me to handle this situation either on the sql server side to feed Azure Search with proper rowset or on the Azure Search side to handle 0:M records per object (document)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if the below will completely solve your problem, but it might help. A couple of observations:

1. Instead of creating a single uber-view flattening everything, you can set up multiple datasource/indexer pairs all writing into the same search index - as long as all of them agree on document id, you can merge the data and assemble your Azure Search documents piece-by-piece from multiple sources.
2. To handle arrays of values, Azure Search has Collection(Edm.String) field type. Since SQL doesn't support arrays natively, you can generate a string field in JSON array format (e.g., ["a", "b", "c"]) and use jsonArrayToStringCollection function as described in [this article](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/search-indexers-customization/).

HTH!